# Case When with CTE SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which it has to return one value.

My query returns 2 rows. But I have to make condition : if my column `[STJH_DATE_ACTION] <= GETDATE()`, I have to show only the first row

If my column `[STJH_DATE_ACTION] < GETDATE()` I want to show second row.

I tried this query :

```sql
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ST_ID, STJ_JOUR ORDER BY A.STJH_DATE_ACTION DESC) AS RN, 
        * 
    FROM 
        bloc.W_TMD_JOUR_HISTORIQUE A
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.ST_ID = 268 AND CTE.STJ_JOUR = 1
```

How can I add the `Case When` expression?

I have this result

[image]

Comment: What is `Gedate()`? If it is the same at `Getdate()`, which I assume is [`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? If `[STJH_DATE_ACTION] < Gedate()` then `[STJH_DATE_ACTION] <= Getdate()` is also true, which makes you question hard to understand.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. The pixels you provided for a result seem to have more than two rows of both pixels and possibly textual data, though your problem description refers to "query returns me 2 two rows." Sample data, in usable form, and corresponding expected results help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would much rather have a minimally reproducible sample code to use. I'm blindly going by your code sample above, and your description. I added a `CASE` expression to your CTE. Then in the main `SELECT`, I order by the `CASE` expression and add `TOP 1` to make sure we only get one row. The only issue I'm not completely knowledgeable on is weather calling `GETDATE()` twice will always produce the same result as I used it.:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by ST_ID, STJ_JOUR order by A.STJH_DATE_ACTION DESC) as RN
        , * 
        , CASE 
            WHEN [STJH_DATE_ACTION] = GETDATE() THEN 1
            WHEN [STJH_DATE_ACTION] < GETDATE() THEN 0
          END as isCurrent
    FROM bloc.W_TMD_JOUR_HISTORIQUE A
)
SELECT TOP 1
    CTE.*
FROM CTE
WHERE 
    CTE.ST_ID = 268 
    AND CTE.STJ_JOUR = 1
ORDER BY CTE.isCurrent DESC
```

Update: `CASE` "expressions" not statements.

Comment: <pedantry> [`Case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an _expression_, not a _statement_, in T-SQL. </pedantry>